# Can a USSD gateway ignore untrusted certificate errors?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, ssl, https, gateway

I have a web service installed on Tomcat. I am using HTTPs to call the web service using a self-signed certificate. Calling this web service through HTTPs from PHP (curl) works fine and I get a normal response.

However, when the same HTTPs is sent to a USSD gateway, it does not return any response. It does with the normal HTTP requests.

I am not familiar with the gateway or its implementation. I only wrote the web service to be called but is there a way that the gateway can ignore the "untrusted certificate error" and proceed to send the HTTPs request to the Tomcat server?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the keystore to the gateways trusted keystores?

Comment: I sent it to the gateway implementers and they said it doesn't support .keystore extension. So I tried a whole different approach with a .jks keystore and sent them a .p12 file which they did add to the trusted keystores, but they said it still doesn't work.